# React Native throwing missing dependency error

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, react-native-web

I'm cloning a existing react-native project with typescript support. But when I tried to install the node_modules package it started to show this error and does not start the project even after installing all the dependencies.

I tried to install "@types/react" manually but got no success. It keeps asking to install types for react.

I also check the Github issue but no-one seems concerned about this issue.

If you able to resolve this issue or know the solution then please do help.

Answer (score 0):

I got to know that the error was due to the breaking changes in the expo-cli.
It simply go away after updating expo-cli to the latest version.

I haven't upgraded the expo-cli but still if caused error because expo blocked the old URL to the server.(I don't under their workflow completely, please refer another source for more clarity)